# OS X Cocoa timer not fired when application on background

Tags: macos, nstimer, sleep, nsthread

A third-party library provides a function I need to call every 100ms. Setting up a timer to do that works very well as long as my app is on foreground. When my app is on background timer works for a while but after a about a minute timer is called only after 10 second delay. The same happened when I created a separate thread with usleep-function. Is there any way I can keep timer running while my app is on background?

Comment: Which version of MacOs?

Comment: Tested on OS X 10.9 Mavericks only so far.

Comment: You can check if app nap is applying using the 'taskinfo' command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [beginActivityWithOptions:reason:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to disable app nap for your application.

Comment: Brilliant, that was the issue. After disabling app nap my timer now keeps running nicely on background.

Answer (score 0):

You should try and re-architect to avoid these sorts of frequent timers, especially when your application is in the background.  Making this sort of change will improve battery life for your users.